# Solidity - Ballot Example

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I have this following **Ballot** contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

/// @title Voting with delegation.
contract Ballot {
// This declares a new complex type which will
// be used for variables later.
// It will represent a single voter.
struct Voter {
    uint weight; // weight is accumulated by delegation
    bool voted;  // if true, that person already voted
    address delegate; // person delegated to
    uint vote;   // index of the voted proposal
}

// This is a type for a single proposal.
struct Proposal {
    bytes32 name;   // short name (up to 32 bytes)
    uint voteCount; // number of accumulated votes
}

address public chairperson;

// This declares a state variable that
// stores a `Voter` struct for each possible address.
mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

// A dynamically-sized array of `Proposal` structs.
Proposal[] public proposals;

/// Create a new ballot to choose one of `proposalNames`.
function Ballot(bytes32[] proposalNames) internal {
    chairperson = msg.sender;
    voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

    // For each of the provided proposal names,
    // create a new proposal object and add it
    // to the end of the array.
    for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
        // `Proposal({...})` creates a temporary
        // Proposal object and `proposals.push(...)`
        // appends it to the end of `proposals`.
        proposals.push(Proposal({
            name: proposalNames[i],
            voteCount: 0
        }));
    }
}

function getProposalsCount() public constant returns(uint) {
    return proposals.length;
}

function getProposal(uint index) public constant returns(bytes32, uint) {
    return (proposals[index].name, proposals[index].voteCount);
}

// Give `voter` the right to vote on this ballot.
// May only be called by `chairperson`.
function giveRightToVote(address voter) public {
    // If the argument of `require` evaluates to `false`,
    // it terminates and reverts all changes to
    // the state and to Ether balances. It is often
    // a good idea to use this if functions are
    // called incorrectly. But watch out, this
    // will currently also consume all provided gas
    // (this is planned to change in the future).
    require((msg.sender == chairperson) && !voters[voter].voted && (voters[voter].weight == 0));
    voters[voter].weight = 1;
}

/// Delegate your vote to the voter `to`.
function delegate(address to) public {
    // assigns reference
    Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
    require(!sender.voted);

    // Self-delegation is not allowed.
    require(to != msg.sender);

    // Forward the delegation as long as
    // `to` also delegated.
    // In general, such loops are very dangerous,
    // because if they run too long, they might
    // need more gas than is available in a block.
    // In this case, the delegation will not be executed,
    // but in other situations, such loops might
    // cause a contract to get "stuck" completely.
    while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)) {
        to = voters[to].delegate;

        // We found a loop in the delegation, not allowed.
        require(to != msg.sender);
    }

    // Since `sender` is a reference, this
    // modifies `voters[msg.sender].voted`
    sender.voted = true;
    sender.delegate = to;
    Voter storage delegate2 = voters[to];
    if (delegate2.voted) {
        // If the delegate already voted,
        // directly add to the number of votes
        proposals[delegate2.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
    } else {
        // If the delegate did not vote yet,
        // add to her weight.
        delegate2.weight += sender.weight;
    }
}

/// Give your vote (including votes delegated to you)
/// to proposal `proposals[proposal].name`.
function vote(uint proposal) public {
    Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
    require(!sender.voted);
    sender.voted = true;
    sender.vote = proposal;

    // If `proposal` is out of the range of the array,
    // this will throw automatically and revert all
    // changes.
    proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
}

/// @dev Computes the winning proposal taking all
/// previous votes into account.
function winningProposal() public constant
        returns (uint winningProposal2)
{
    uint winningVoteCount = 0;
    for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
        if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
            winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
            winningProposal2 = p;
        }
    }
}

// Calls winningProposal() function to get the index
// of the winner contained in the proposals array and then
// returns the name of the winner
function winnerName() public constant
        returns (bytes32 winnerName2)
{
    winnerName2 = proposals[winningProposal()].name;
}
}
```

I have it deployed at rinkeyby (0xC9F933b8326FF672259445459FA720667939A7a9) with initial array ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']. When I try to run following funcations from web3js, I get 0x or null values. Here's the javascript code:

```
        var Web3 = require('web3');

        if (typeof window.web3 !== "undefined" && typeof window.web3.currentProvider !== "undefined") {
            var web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            var web3 = web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider());
        }

        var selectedAccount;

        web3.eth.getAccounts(function (err, accounts) { if (!err && accounts.length > 0) selectedAccount = accounts[0]; });

        var abiArray = [{ "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "proposal", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "vote", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "proposals", "outputs": [{ "name": "name", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "voteCount", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "chairperson", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "to", "type": "address" }], "name": "delegate", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "winningProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "winningProposal2", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getProposalsCount", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "voter", "type": "address" }], "name": "giveRightToVote", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "name": "voters", "outputs": [{ "name": "weight", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "voted", "type": "bool" }, { "name": "delegate", "type": "address" }, { "name": "vote", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "index", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "getProposal", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }, { "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "winnerName", "outputs": [{ "name": "winnerName2", "type": "bytes32" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "name": "proposalNames", "type": "bytes32[]" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }];

        var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

        var contractInstance = MyContract.at('0xC9F933b8326FF672259445459FA720667939A7a9');

        function get_data() {
            var callback = function (error, result) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
                else {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            };
            contractInstance.getProposalsCount(callback);
            contractInstance.getProposal(0, callback);
            contractInstance.getProposal(1, callback);
            contractInstance.chairperson(callback);    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the Array of Strings like this  [ "0x123...", "0x345..." ]